# Oracle SQLDeveloper time zone issue

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, when I use its date/time control to populate a value for a record's TIMESTAMP column, the result is something like:

`19-APR-18 03.39.31.539000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK`.

This will cause problem later on.  How can I change SQL Developer configure, so that it will be:

```
19-APR-18 03.39.31.539000000 PM -4:00.
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the timezone drop down

go to the bottom

[image]

You'll see the following DML sent to the db

```
UPDATE ... 
SET ... = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(
     '2018-04-19 18:23:49.303884000 -04:00',
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR');
```